# Cent os error after installing

Tags: centos, system-installation

[image]
After installing centos in hp laptop i m getting this error and not able to use the system.

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  **;-)** That looks like a hardware error to me as I can just discern `PCIe Bus Error: ... type=Physical`

Comment: How far through the installation process did you get before you saw these errors? Were there any other messages that appeared first?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a driver issue. To solve it, you can try one of the three following kernel parameters: `pcie_aspm=off` [1], `pci=nomsi` [2], `pci=noaer` [2].

Sources:

1: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/PCIe_Bus_Error_Status_00001100

2: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected

Comment: Hi, is there a reference on how to change these variables. I am using RHEL 7 and it has different grub config than ubuntu. Also, I am not able to boot into the system, so I need to make temporary update, before making it permanent